# Downgrading Magento

Tags: magento, payment-gateway, payment-processing, ccavenue

I'm using Magento 1.4.1.1 for my webstore. The payment processor supports only 1.4.0.0. I realized this only just now when I was dreaming up of opening the store. Duh! Poor planning.

What's the way out?

Will downgrading help? Wat are the implications of that?

Thanks for any and all inputs.

Comment: Is it not working or just wasn't checked with 1.4.1.1?

Comment: The payment processor integrates only up to 1.4.0.0.

Comment: it's probably easier to fix the payment method for 1.4.1.* than downgrade and insert all settings all over again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of anyone ever having successfully downgraded Magento. That said, a few considerations:

- Are you using version control like you should be? If so, you should have a copy of the site and database from just before the upgrade. You should be able to use this as a starting point. This is your most optimistic route by far.
- If no version control, you can download both of the versions and use `diff` to get the changes. Doing this in reverse theoretically creates a backwards patch.
- If you've stayed out of the core code entirely, the code change could be nearly as simple as replacing `app/code/core`.
- Even if you do downgrade the code, the data structures between versions have probably changed, so you'll need someone experienced to find those changes and tell you have to back-patch your database. This is, to say the least, perilous.

Overall, I wouldn't want to undertake this task. As Anton said in the comments, you'll probably have an easier time getting integration done than reverting the changes.

Best of luck!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: I don't think he ever had v1.3.2.4 running on his install, so svn probably isn't going to help :(